# How do I re-hide the bar with "View, Tool, Item"?

Tags: interface

I clicked the arrow that popped this out, so now how do I put it back?

[image: Red box highlighting the a with "View", "Tool", and "Item" in Blender]

Answer (score 16):

It's named Sidebar.
There is three ways to hide it:

1. Drag the corner of sidebar to the right:

[image: Drag the corner of the sidebar to the right]

2. View3D > Menu > View > Sidebar (visible if checked):

[image: View3D > Menu > View > Sidebar]

3. Shortcut: N, as mentioned in the previous screenshot.